# How do I create a custom XML Response for a Spring Boot Rest Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I`m new to Spring Boot and I want to add a new tag in the xml response and change the name of all the other xml tags.

The new xml tag should have the name PDF and it will contain a base 64 encoded file.

This is my controller method:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/byids/{statementsid}/{username}/{agency}")
    public ResponseEntity<BTStatement> getStatementsByIds(@PathVariable("statementsid") int stmtId,
                                                          @PathVariable("username") String username,
                                                          @PathVariable("agency") String agency,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "format", required = true, defaultValue = "PDF") String format) {
        BTStatement stmt;
        ResponseEntity<BTStatement> re=null;
        try {
            stmt = btStatementService.findById(stmtId);
            re= new ResponseEntity<>(btStatementService.findById(stmtId), HttpStatus.OK);
            return re;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
            re= new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            return re;
        }
    }
```

In order to make all my methods return data in the xml format i created a WebConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements  WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it seems to work.

```
@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name="Statement")
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD )
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATEMENTS")
class BTStatement {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;
    @Column(name = "BT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    private String AccNumber;
    @Column(name = "CUST_NO")
    private String ClientID;
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATED")
    private Date Date_Gen;
    @Column(name = "BANK_DATE")
    private Date EOD;
    @Column(name = "FREQUENCY_TYPE")
    private String FrequencyType;
    @Column(name = "IBAN_AC_NO")
    private String IBAN;
    @Column(name = "BT_STMT_NUMBER")
    private int StatementNumber;
    @Transient
    private String PDF; 

    public void downloadPdf()
    {
        this.PDF="**********";
    }

}
```

I also created a XmlConfig class to make the xml annotations work.

```
@Configuration
public class XmlConfig {

    /*You are using JAXB specific annotations, but Jackson to marshall your response. To make JAXB annotations work with Jackson, you have to include the jackson-module-jaxb-annotations inside your pom.xml*/
    @Bean
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer() {
        return (mapperBuilder) -> mapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    }
}
```

And here is the controller method.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/byids/{statementsid}/{username}/{agency}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<BTStatement> getStatementsByIds(@PathVariable("statementsid") int stmtId,
                                                          @PathVariable("username") String username,
                                                          @PathVariable("agency") String agency,
                                                          @RequestParam(name = "format", required = true, defaultValue = "PDF") String format) {
        BTStatement stmt;
        ResponseEntity<BTStatement> re=null;
        logger.info("getting statement: "+stmtId);
        try {
            stmt = btStatementService.findById(stmtId);
            stmt.downloadPdf();
            re= ResponseEntity.ok(stmt);
            logger.info("got statement: "+stmt);
            return re;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
            re= ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            logger.error("couldn`t get statement: "+stmtId+" "+e.toString());
            return re;
        }
        //Manipulate the response directly
        //Spring also lets us access the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse object directly; we only have to declare it as a method argument: HttpServletResponse response
        //response.getWriter().println();
        //Since Spring provides abstractions and additional capabilities above the underlying implementation, we shouldn't manipulate the response this way.
    }
```

For more info on this you can check this link: https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-annotations/

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)